# SQL DELETE with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Why the following query doesn't work? What is the best way to delete the following five tables row in SQL? How can I fix it?

```
//$id = $this->input->post('id');
$id = '65';
    $this->db->query("
        DELETE table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4, table_5
        FROM table_1
            JOIN  table_2   ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
            JOIN  table_3   ON table_2.h_id = table_3.h_id          
            JOIN  table_4   ON table_1.id = table_4.rela
            JOIN  table_5   ON table_2.h_id = table_5.h_id
        WHERE table_1.id =".floor($id));
```

**Update:**

**table_1.id** => this have id `65`
**table_2.rela** => this have rela `65`
**table_2.h_id** => this have h_id `11`
**table_3.h_id** => this have h_id `11`
**table_4.rela** => this have rela `65`
**table_5.h_id** => this have h_id `11`

**Update 2:**

in `table_1.id` one row have `65` and also is for `table_2` and `table_4` that have `rela 65` (`table_1.id = table_2.rela => 65 = 65, table_1.id = table_4.rela => 65 = 65`) now in `table_2` we have a column name h_id that have number `11` and it is set with `h_id` in other tables[`table_3`, `table_5`].

How with there this relationship can get a `id` from `table_1` and delete other rows in their tables.

i mane is this: (with have one `id` from `table_1` we can delete other rows relationship with it in their tables, in following is a example from this relationship)

> `table_1.id` = `65` => `table_4.rela` = `65` => `table_2.rela` = `65`
>   **->** *`table_2.h_id`* = `11` => `table_3.h_id` = `11` => `table_5.h_id` = `11`.

**UPDATE 3:**

**Who can help me for my problem, there is a guy? I don't get still answers for Question's.**

Comment: what the hell are you tryin' to do?

Comment: The first place you always start is with the error message. What was the error message?

Comment: Who can help me for my problem, there is a guy? I don't get still answers for Question's.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the rows of your tables one by one.

Its also possible to define your table for cascade delete... If you do this you only need delete only one row in one table. The other related rows in other table will deleted automaticly.

```
        CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
        `typeId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `type` (`typeId`)
        CONSTRAINT `myForeignKey` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`)
          REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

hope this helps

Comment: You can delete from several tables at the same time as stated here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @dknaack - i don't understand your sql, how it done delete in five table(table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4, table_5)?

Comment: Make a mistake, i want delete rows in tables. how is it?

Comment: @dknaack: sorry that was not for you. Did not tag the author.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to delete the tables, but you probably mean you want to delete the row from the tables. Deleting or dropping a table means removing the table and all of its contents.

I see one problem. You mention table_1 in the first part, but not again. I'll assume the first table is table_1 and not tour_foreign.

```
    DELETE table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4, table_5
    FROM table_1
        INNER JOIN  table_2   ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
        INNER JOIN  table_3   ON table_2.h_id = table_3.h_id          
        INNER JOIN  table_4   ON table_1.id = table_4.rela
        INNER JOIN  table_5   ON table_2.h_id = table_5.h_id
    WHERE table_1.id = 5
```

From the mysql docs it looks like you can also leave out the list of tables if you want to delete the rows from all of those tables:

```
    DELETE FROM table_1
        INNER JOIN  table_2   ON table_1.id = table_2.rela
        INNER JOIN  table_3   ON table_2.h_id = table_3.h_id          
        INNER JOIN  table_4   ON table_1.id = table_4.rela
        INNER JOIN  table_5   ON table_2.h_id = table_5.h_id
    WHERE table_1.id = 5
```

Comment: No, make a mistake, i want delete rows in tables. how is it?

Comment: Try with inner join as the docs suggests. I revised my answer.

Comment: Please read my update 2 in first post and tell me about my problem that what do i do for it?

Comment: It have this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2' at line 2

`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to do this at the app layer. MySQL provides the ability to delete child rows using foreign key constraints (ON DELETE CASCADE). Check your current schema and see if they are already available:

```
mysql> show create table child_table;
```

If there is a foreign key constraint available you should see something like:

```
CONSTRAINT `constraint_id` FOREIGN KEY (`some_id`) REFERENCES `some_table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

What this means is if you delete a row from 'some_table', any rows in 'child_table' which reference the same id as 'some_table' will automatically be deleted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for more info.

If you need to do this at the app layer then you should really consider a transaction, I am assuming you are using PDO, although it may work with mysqli. Below is a potential solution, as such I assume no responsibility for any data loss you may incur.

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();

try {

   $this->db->execute('DELETE FROM table_1 WHERE id = 65');
   $this->db->execute('DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE rela = 65');
   $this->db->execute('DELETE FROM table_3 WHERE h_id = 11');
   $this->db->execute('DELETE FROM table_4 WHERE rela = 65');
   $this->db->execute('DELETE FROM table_5 WHERE h_id = 11');

   $this->db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {

    error_log($e->getMessage());

    $this->db->rollBack();

    $e = null; // PHP is notorious for not cleaning exceptions very well so force it
}
```

Comment: In other tables there is not row id, Some of them are `h_id` and some other are `rela`, values their in table row are different. please see my update in first post.

Comment: Did you check to see if there are already any existing FK constraints?

Comment: I don't understand your mean"already any existing FK constraints"?

Comment: Make a mistake, i want delete rows in tables. how is it?

Comment: FK=Foreign Key. An FK constraint tells mysql that a column in one table is related to a column in another table. This allows you to maintain referential integrity and implement cascade deletes. You should read up on this subject.

Comment: I explained how to check in my post. If you are going to do this at the app level then you should wrap the deletes within a transaction so you don't end up with corrupted data.

Comment: Please read my update 2 in first post and tell me about my problem that what do i do for it?

Comment: NO, values `65` and `11` only was a example, i get just table_1.id with `$_POST[]` => `$id = $this->input->post('id');
` and other rows get by relationship their together that i say in update 2 first post about it. Do can done it with JOIN?

Comment: Sorry friend, I cannot help you with a join delete, perhaps refer to the other posts for guidance.